# Creating a testing script which 'skips' file uploads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a testing script for my team. So far it works fine - it goes to the login form and attempts to login using the details you entered, if that fails it goes to a job description and attempts to apply for a job, selecting a random answer for each screening question until it gets to the actual application form. Unfortunately the application form includes a file upload control, which I don't appear to be able to skip over. Does anyone have any idea if I could actually skip over it or somehow click it? I am using FF7 and from previous posts I can see that apparently FF4 does it - but FF7 doesn't appear to make file uploads clickable through JS.... any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Richard

Comment: Can you just remove the element, assuming the upload destination won't choke on a missing element? Or remove the upload control and replace it with an ordinary file input type.

Comment: 'fraid not - there is validation to make sure it is populated.. I don't think there is any way to remove the validation as that is output by the core product.

Comment: If the form submit itself requires an attached file, then you'll have to use John's answer below - an automated testing tool.

Comment: I think we can probably just live with uploading manually. The primary goal for this is to give support, QA and dev teams the ability to be able to quickly go to a specific page, regardless of whether they're logged in or not. I already have the skills I need in jQuery for this, except skipping the file uploads. I don't think it is worth learning another tool for this. Currently I have cut the time taken to create an account by at least half, so I'm happy with that. Also read my comment below - people have already tried selenium, and not got very far from what I hear.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript can't access file upload inputs for security reasons (e.g. prevent malicious upload of user's files). For this kind of testing you should use a browser automation tool like Selenium http://seleniumhq.org/ (or in web service form https://saucelabs.com/).

Comment: I was talking to my interviewer today about this script, and demoed it; he said it is brilliant and long LONG overdue. He also said that their QA team is trying to develop something in selenium, but my script actually works a lot better than what they've done so far (and I've spent less time on this than they have).. looks like userscripts are the way to go for us. Besides with mine we can save data either on an individual frontend level, server level or ALL servers level.